# Why is my function returning two duplicate values?

Tags: python, duplicates, set

I'm doing a practice problem where I need to find the longest common prefix in a list of strings.

Example:

```
Input: strs = ["flower","flow","flight"]
Output: "fl"
```

I'm approaching this as follows:

```
def my_function(strs):

  ### get the length of shortest string in list and assign to "window"

  min_len = min([len(x) for x in strs])
  window = min_len

  ### chop all items in list to length of shortest item

  for i in range(window):
    if window == 0:

      return ''

    strs = [x[:window] for x in strs]

  ### Check the length of the set() of all items. If it's longer than 1, 
  ### shorten the window and re-check

    if len(set(strs)) == 1:
      answer = list(set(strs))
      
      return answer[0]

    else: 
      window += -1
```

When I use the test case given above, my function returns:

```
fl
fl
```

Why am I getting this duplication?

Comment: How do you call the function? With `print(my_function(strs))` I get the expected result.

Comment: @Matthias Yeah I am too. When I posted this, I'd not defined the function. Basically, everything existed except the very first line of code ('def my_function(strs):"), and the return statements were print() instead of returns. For some reason putting essentially the same code in a function body corrected the problem. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You're using a weird loop where you increment "window" with the "for", but decrement it based on a condition. This causes an inconsistent iteration.

Either use a `while` loop and modify the counter manually, or use a `for` loop and don't modify the counter.

That said your approach of not so efficient, rather check the characters in parallel position after position:

```
def prefix(strs):
    out = []
    for x in zip(*strs):
        if len(set(x)) == 1:
            out.append(x[0])
        else:
            break
    return ''.join(out)

prefix(strs)
```

Output: `'fl'`

Comment: Thanks, your explanation was helpful! I ended up using a while loop. I'll post the solution. This is a problem I was trying to solve on Leetcode. When you submit a response, they evaluate it not just for correctness, but also for execution time and memory usage. My function's execution time was 36ms with memory usage of 14MB. Your function came in at 47ms and 13.9MB, so slightly better on memory, but a bit worse on runtime. However, your code was more efficient in terms of number of lines written :)

Answer (score 0):

With @mozway's help, I was able to successfully execute the function using a `while` statement:

```
def prefix(strs):
  min_len = min([len(x) for x in strs])
  window = min_len

  for i in range(window):
    while window > 0:
      strs = [x[:window] for x in strs]
      
      if len(set(strs)) == 1:
        answer = list(set(strs))

        return answer[0]

      else:
        window += -1
      
  return ''
```